# Error: Execution failed for task

Tags: android, parse-platform, gradle

I've created a project that connected to the web server parse.com
Now I encounter an error that I can not fix it

```
****build.gradle(Module:app)****

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/AnimRes.class
```

Here is the code:

```
enterapply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android
 {
    compileSdkVersion 21

    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig
 {
        applicationId "app.chat.chattapp"

        multiDexEnabled true

        minSdkVersion 6
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.9.3'
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
//    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
//    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
//    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

The code is [image: here]

Comment: Hi. I though t I would let you know I edited your post a bit. The first thing I did was format the link that you had to an image, as the link can be confusing. Also, I formatted your error as code, this makes it easier to read, and is common in the SO community. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   android/support/annotation/AnimRes.class

Problem is here , **Duplicate** Entry . Same Library calling 2 times.
 That's why have problem .

**Don't**

```
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.9.3'
```

**Do**

```
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.9.3'
```

**Suggestions**

Do add this

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

**Finally**

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.9.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync**